# How to load data to make them visible in an ActivityList?

Tags: android

I'm relatively new to Android and have the following question. I have a local DB on the device from which I want to display the content in an ActivityList. Let's say there is a table "person" on the DB containing general information like "name, surname etc."
Every row in the table should be displayed as an item within the ActivityList.

I know that there exists a sort of Adapter with which I can directly fill the ActivityList with my table data, but is this the way to do it? 
Isn't it better to load all the data at startup and then hold them for the entire session and pass the data from one activity to another(or make them static..) if necessary, instead of loading the data every time I change to another Activity?

If I would have a normal Java application I would load the Data at startup and then just work with the loaded objects (at least for reasonable data sets).

Doesn't it make sense for an Android App too?

I will up-rate every answer that makes sense to me.

Thanks!
Slash

Comment: Check out this tutorial: http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/ --- for starters, doing it in `onCreate()` is okay. For a real-world app and lots of data, you should follow the advice in the answers to use an `AsyncTask` or go the `ContentProvider`-and-`LoaderManager` route.

Comment: And no, don't load it all and pass it around between activities. Using an `Adapter` instance to bind data from a query to a (list)view is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a look at the [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

You can use it to query your database and then show the content in the ListView using a CursorAdapter.

Comment: There isn't a reason for Mr. Slash to use a ContentProvider unless he wishes to expose the database content to other applications. He can still obtain a cursor directly from the database and use a CursorAdapter without the overhead of a ContentProvider.

Comment: A `ContentProvider` can greatly simplify client code even when used privately in an application, especially with the Android 3.x (or compat lib v4) `LoaderManager` framework. It's probably overkill to start off with a CP when beginning Android, but in the end there's little difference between a custom database class and a database class implementing the `ContentProvider` interface.

Comment: @Maria Even tough you didn't really answered my question I voted you up, since your suggestion isn't completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an Adapter if you want to work with ListView. So, that is a must. And you can set the Adapter data from your Activity.

As for the "sense" question, it probably makes sense. But as always it depends on a few things:

Will this data be used through out the application? Then it absolutely makes sense to load it once and use it everywhere. How you do that is up to your needs, static access or passing the data, all should work.

And DB access is always expensive. And if you have lots of rows, the loading process from the database can be extremely slow. So, again, load it once and use it everywhere is a good plan.

But be careful about blocking the UI thread when you load this data. You should never access DB from your UI thread. Instead use a worker thread or AsyncTask.

Comment: Yes I'm going to use the data through out the application, but just parts of it. E.g. On the detail view, I would just need the data of one specific table row. So it makes probably more sense to load just the data that is required by the activity rather then load everything on startup. But nevertheless I voted you up, since in some cases it could make sense.